# vmstat IO stats: why the high bo during a download?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, performance, io

On my RHEL 4 machine, I was downloading a huge file (2.5GB)..I was checking the output of vmstat and was especially curious about seeing the disk IO using bi and bo. I know iostat is a better tool suited for this but didn't have it installed on this machine.

Anyways, I was expecting bi (bytes in) to be high during the download but found the exact opposite...bo (bytes out) was very high during the download where as bi was mostly 0 with occasional numbers??

Also, without iostat, is there a better tool than vmstat that is available Out of the Box in a Red Hat machine?

Answer (score 6):

The `bi`/`bo` figures are for block devices. Conventional network adapters are not block devices, so network I/O doesn't show up there; it doesn't show up in `iostat` either.

The high `bo` values come from writing the downloaded data to your disks. "Out" data going *to* the device, "in" for data coming *from* it.

For monitoring network activity, you could look at [iptraf-ng](https://fedorahosted.org/iptraf-ng/) (ncurses-based) or [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) (web-based), but I doubt they'll be installed on your system if `iostat` isn't - just ask your friendly sysadmin to add the required packages :)

Answer (score 0):

Vmstat command provides virtual Memory statistics. If you check [vmstat command](http://roundoverlinux.blogspot.com/2012/10/check-linux-systems-performance-by.html) then visit this link.

You can check downloading speed by netstat commmand as well. But for option, I need to check this command again. Please check for netstat command might it will help you.

There is one link..might it will help you. [Click Here](http://roundoverlinux.blogspot.com/2012/10/check-cpu-usage-in-linux.html)